# Entity Reference Multiple Migration

Tags: 7, entities, migrations

I'm writing a migration module, and I have an entity reference multiple field in which users can choose what type of content they want to add.

I need to map to this field from multiple sourceMigrations, but each one of the migration tables has different id column name.

I know i can do something similar to this for a single migration

```
  $query->leftJoin('Wet', 'w', 'p.AUTO = `w.wt-stauto`');

  $this->addFieldMapping('field_add_system', 'buildNums')
    ->separator(',')
    ->sourceMigration('novaWet');
```

I know this isn't correct but in my head it would need to be something like

```
   $this->addFieldMapping('field_add_system', 'wetIds', 'dryIds', 'pumpIds')
    ->separator(',')
    ->sourceMigration('Wet', 'Dry' 'Pump');
```

Anyone accomplished something like this?

Comment: If `sourceMigration` accepts a string or an array, then first you'd have to pass `sourceMigration(array('foo', 'bar', 'baz'))`. Anyway, mikeryan would probably knock this question out. However, _I think_ some answers may lie here which sounds similar: https://www.drupal.org/node/1270668#comment-4971714